# Flask + mod_wsgi: client denied by server configuration

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've been trying out quite a many things to the level of high frustration when trying to get Flask run with Apache + mod_wsgi.

Basically I've done the following tutorials:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#installing-mod-wsgi
http://www.lonesomedev.com/?p=169

But on browser I'm getting the following error:

---

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

### Error 403

And in Apache error.log the following:

[Fri May 03 17:17:06 2013] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /home/user1/Develop/flask_dbadmin.wsgi

---

I'm running OpenSuse 11.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like Apache doesn't have access to the object in question. Make sure you have an account set up for this specific reason and give the files access this account. Then use `chown` to set the access to these files for that user. In a development environment that can be for example the Apache account.

```
chown -R wwwrun:www /home/user1/Develop/
```

Or you could give everyone access, but I wouldn't recommend this.

```
chmod 777 -R /home/user1/Develop/
```

If that doesn't work you may need to manually allow access to the wsgi files in your apache config.

It should look something like this.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flask_dbadmin user=wwwrun group=www threads=5
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ........

   <Directory /home/user1/Develop/ >
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>

   <Files flask_dbadmin.wsgi>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: No worries. I hope it helped. :D

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I tried all those tricks and the same problem persists... :-/

Comment: Can you post your apache config for this site?

Comment: And can you do a `ls -l` in the terminal where you have your wsgi file and provide us with the output?

Comment: And the whole app structure is at the moment - after many other trials - with 0777 for all: -rwxrwxrwx  1 wwwrun www     241 May  3 16:56 flask_dbadmin.wsgi

Comment: I added an additional line for your apache config.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see your additional line... which one would you add to the config?

Comment: `<Directory /home/user1/Develop/ >
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
</Directory>`

Comment: I would def recommend that you post your config using the link above (`pastebin.com`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, again. Tried it but same result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29379/discussion-between-ajussis-and-eandersson)

Comment: Can you paste the content of your .wsgi file?

Comment: Setting 0777 permissions on everything is a bad idea. Changing a whole user to be owned by Apache is also a bad idea if that is a normal user account.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I agree. I assumed this was for an dev machine, but I updated my answer.

Answer (score 16):

If you tried things mentioned [Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18392741/897221) here and it still doesn't work chances are your wsgi script alias path is outside path mentioned in  `<Directory>` block.

**You need a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` block for every Alias.**
So for example,

for 
`WSGIScriptAlias / /home/stark/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi`

you would need

```
 <Directory /home/stark/FlaskApp>
       Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

Comment: `You need a <Directory> or <Location> block for every Alias` **every** is the word. I was just gonna commit suicide because of this error.